# What does permeate mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar, american-english

"I like girls who are just as confident without make-up on than when they are when it permeates their face."

I saw it on Twitter.

In this sentence, does permeate mean when makeup covers the whole face?

Comment: Yes, though some would argue it's used incorrectly there.

Comment: I agree Dan. Maybe "permeates the entire race" would make more sense.

Comment: Permeats isn't a word though?

Comment: Did you look up *permeate* in a dictionary? If you do it will answer your question.

Comment: @Hector, it's the infelicitous application of the word "permeates", which typically has a volumetric (three-dimensional) quality or connotation. But you got the understood the intended concept: a face *covered* in makeup.

Comment: Hector: I was making fun. Seriously, it's not the best choice of words, but looking up in the dictionary should tell you it sorta makes sense. 'permeate' doesn't work well with a surface (like a face). What is probably intended is 'covers thickly'.

Comment: Hello, Hector! Welcome to ELU and thank you for participating. There’s a lot to learn about the site, like how to ask a good question or provide a good answer. I’d recommend you start by taking the [**tour**](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour). Have fun, and we’ll see you around.

Answer (score 4):

> "I like girls who are just as confident without make-up on than when
>   they are when it ***permeates*** their face."

[Permeate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/permeate) is a ***[malapropism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/malapropism)*** in that sentence. Normally, it means:

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Spread throughout (something); pervade:

You would use *permeate* to describe an odor in the air:

> *The smell of death permeated the room.*

You could use it to describe an attitude in an organization:

> *Their pessimism permeates the market.*

You can spread make up all over the surface of a face, but not all ***through*** a face.

***Malapropism***:

> NOUN
>
> The mistaken use of a word in place of a similar-sounding one, often
>   with an amusing effect

Also correcting the inappropriate construction of the comparison:

> "I like girls who are just as confident without make-up as
>   they are when it ***dominates*** their face."